# Read/Write text files in Python

Tags: python, file, exception

I'm fairly new to Python and don't fully understand all items and I've been given a base for a programme and I need to alter bits, here's what I have so far:

```
    import sys, os

    filename   = 'C:\main\in.txt'
    resultFile = 'C:\main\out.txt'

    try:
       file = open( filename, "w" )
    except Exception, e:
        logger.critical( "Failed to create file \"%s\" : %s" % ( filename, e )

    for name, value in brg.iteritems():
        if -1 == string.find( name, "CTRL" ) and name not in [ "name", "type" ]:
            file.write( "%s = %s\n" % ( name, value ) )
            file.close()

   # run the Fortran programme

    resultCode = os.system( '%sC:\main\Debug\main.exe -i %s -o %s.result' % ( options[ OPTION_script_path ], filename, filename ) ) 

    # Read the results

    try:
        file = open( resultFile, "r" ) 
    except Exception, e:
        logger.critical( "Failed to create file \"%s\" : %s" % ( resultFile, e ) 

        regexp = re.compile( "^(?P<name>.*)\\s*=\\s*(?P<value>.*)$" )
        for row in file.xreadlines():
        row = row.strip( "\\r\\n \\t" )
        m = regexp.match( row )
        if m:
                name = m.group( "name" )
                value = m.group( "value" )
                brg[ name ] = value
```

I am completely lost as to why it doesn't currently work as it's finding a Syntax error with: for name, value in bearing.iteritems():

I'm not sure whether some mistakes are due to indentation..

I also don't quite understand the last part. I have an output text file and this is what the final part is reading. I have however don't understand (in particular) this line:

```
regexp = re.compile( "^(?P<name>.*)\\s*=\\s*(?P<value>.*)$" )
```

With the RE's, I don't understand exactly what it means by 'matching' what is the ^, $ and ?P matching to what? Also what does 'regexp' represent?

Thank you for your time =)

Comment: "Syntax error with: for name, value in bearing.iteritems()"?  Please include the actual syntax error output in your question.

Comment: if your code is the real code, brg (or bearing) is not defined before you use it into the loop...

Comment: "I ... don't understand (in particular) this line:"  and "in very simple terms" is hard to do.  Please clarify what you do and do not understand about that line.  We don't know how "simple" you mean.  We don't know what parts you do understand.  Please provide some summary of what you think it might be so we can extend and correct your statements.

Comment: Be careful: filename   = 'C:\main\in.txt' works but '\n.txt' would not. Because \n is a newline character. Use double backslashes or r'C:\main\in.txt'

Comment: @user982297: Please stop adding comments to your question.  Please **update** your question to indicate what you do not understand.  After **updating** your question, please remove the two comments related to what you do (and don't) understand about the regular expression.  It's hard to synthesize a coherent question from a lot  of comments.  It helps if you **update** your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        logger.critical( "Failed to create file \"%s\" : %s" % ( filename, e )
```

Has 2 left `(` and only 1 right `)`.  This appears to be a syntax error.

Since the statement isn't complete, Python continues parsing.  The error message shows up on the following line.

---

Read this: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax.  Then **update** your question with more specific aspects of the regular expression which confuse you.  Regular expressions are a (potentially) deep topic.

Comment: BTW, AFAIK `logger.critical` accepts as well the form `logger.critical( "Failed to create file \"%s\" : %s", filename, e)`.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I didn't see that!